# fork + exec + caller should not wait for child

Tags: perl, exec, fork

I have two scripts script_a and script_b.
script_a calls script_b. script_b forks two processes. As shown below.

script_a waits for both the parent and child of script_b to finish.
I want script_a to continue without waiting for the child process of script_b.

What I have done for this is in script_b, I have added the following code.

```
if (! $f_id) {
    close STDOUT;
    close STDERR;
    exec("sleep 10; echo 'i am child'");
}
```

This works for me. script_a no longer waits for the child process.

My question here is,
1. Is this the right way to do this?
2. Do parent and the child process share the same STDOUT and STDERR and would I end up in trouble if there is a race condition?
3. Are there better ways to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

script_a.pl

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl
print `script_b.pl`;
```

script_b.pl

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl

$f_id = fork();

if (! $f_id) {
    exec("sleep 10; echo 'i am child'");
}

if ($f_id) {
    print "i am parent\n";
}
```

Comment: 1) you may just fork on script_a, but without knowing your **real** problem is hard to tell. 2) The backquote operator just sets a new STDOUT for the child. STDERR is shared though.

Comment: @Salva This is a downsized version of my actual code so it might seem like I can just fork on script_a, but it is not an option for me in the real senario. Would the parent and child in script_b share same STDOUT and STDERR?

Comment: The **STDOUT/STDERR** aren't shared. To begin with when a child is created all descriptors are inherited from parent. They can be independently manipulated once forked.

Comment: Do *script_a* and *script_b* need to communicate? Your sample suggests that A wants B's output, but is that representative of the real programs? Why isn't `fork` an option in *script_a*?

Comment: @GregBacon From a dummy script (script_a) I launch my actual command (script_b) capture its exit status and based on exit status send mails. As part of its execution this actual command forks. But I am just interested in the parents return value and do not want to wait for the child to complete.

Comment: Process in summary is not the right way to do it aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `` in script_a. We have redirected the STDOUT and STDERR in script_a.
Something like

script_a

```
system("script_b.pl > /var/tmp/out_file 2>&1");
```

script_b

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl

$f_id = fork();

if (! $f_id) {
    exec("sleep 10; echo 'i am child'");
}

if ($f_id) {
    print "i am parent\n";
}
```

This way the caller didnot wait for the child in exec to complete.

Thanks for the help here.

Answer (score 0):

**`` backticks** in perl wait for the command to complete. So if you don't want parent process to wait put in **sytem(command &)** in background.

Comment: I want to wait for the parent to return. But i do not want to wait for the child. Could you let me know if the solution that I have put forth  has any issues?